# VS Code Material Icon not rendering icon for certain folders

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VScode extension Material Icon for give folder icons but lately it's not rendering properly for certains folders even if there are in the icon library

here is the image of the folder with the icon:

[image]

and as you can see that the folder Icon is exist on the library

[image]

as some of the solutions was to edit material icons setting to target react-redux active icon pack

[image]

still not working well

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm not getting "specific" theme for folders like: presentation, domain, bloc, and all (for flutter)... any help would be appreciated!
Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have overridden the association in the settings. As for the documentation of Material Icons Theme, it's a bit confusing and incomplete, so this is a workaround, add this to `settings.json`

```json
"material-icon-theme.folders.associations": {
    "firebase": "firebase"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Open `settings` and search for `material icon active icon pack` and change options to `react_redux` and while creating folders do not use the prefix `redux`.
[image]

Then create your folder without prefix like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still asked but to tell you I had the same issue recently and the problem was the font used in vs code I changed it and all seems to work fine .

Comment: Can you share the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I have found a workaround as mentioned in git. here is how you can do that:

- please add this below code snippet in `settings.json`. You can modify these values by looking up the labels at [official page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme)

  ```
  "material-icon-theme.folders.associations": {
    "presentation": "layout",
    "presentations": "layout",
    "bloc": "Redux-store",
    "domain": "Rules",
    "features": "App",
  }
  ```